# I want to show a progressbar while downloading from a database, but I am not sure where to include it in my code

Tags: python, tkinter

I followed this link, which shows how to create a progressbar in Tkinter.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-download-progress-bar-in-tkinter

It seems simple enough

```
    #Define a function
def start():
   task=10
   x=0
   while(x<task):
      time.sleep(1)
      bar['value']+=10
      x+=1
      win.update_idletasks()
```

But I have no idea how I can implement this so it matches with my own code. I made a code that validates and download pdf files from url addresses stored in a database.
Here is the entire code.

```
import validators
import requests
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time

def database_downloader():
    # Check drivers
    for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
        print(driver)

    # Define server and database
    DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    SERVER = '...\MSSQLSERVER01'
    DATABASE = 'TEST_DATABASE'

    # Create connection string
    CONNECTION_STRING = "Driver={driver}; " \
                        "Server={server}; " \
                        "Database={database}; " \
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" \
        .format(driver=DRIVER, server=SERVER, database=DATABASE)

    # Connect to database
    connection_object: pyodbc.Connection = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)

    # Create cursor object
    cursor_object: pyodbc.Cursor = connection_object.cursor()

    # Read primary URL from database

    # Fetch records from database
    sql_select = "SELECT Filename, PDF_Url1, PDF_Url2, " \
                 "Download_Status FROM TABLE"
    records = cursor_object.execute(sql_select).fetchall()

    # Loop through the database records

    for row in records:
        if row:
            # Check if URL in first row is valid
            if validators.url(str(row[1])):
                print(f"{row[0]} - Url is valid")

                # If URL in first row is valid, check if it can be reached

                try:
                    get = requests.get(row[1], timeout=10)
                    if get.status_code == 200:
                        print(f"{row[1]}: is reachable")

                        # Download the URL

                        r = requests.get(row[1], allow_redirects=True)
                        open(row[0], 'wb').write(r.content)
        
                    else:
                        print(f"{row[1]}: is Not reachable")
                except BaseException as error:
                    print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error))

            #If URL in first row is invalid or dead, try same procedure for row 2 instead.

            elif validators.url(str(row[2])):
                print(f"{row[0]} - Url is valid")
                url_valid_list.append(row[2])
                try:
                    get = requests.get(row[2], timeout=10)
                    if get.status_code == 200:
                        print(f"{row[2]}: is reachable")

                        r = requests.get(row[1], allow_redirects=True)
                        open(row[0], 'wb').write(r.content)
    
                    else:
                        print(f"{row[2]}: is Not reachable")
                except BaseException as error:
                    print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error))
            else:
                print(f"{row[0]} - Url is invalid")
        else:
            print(f"{row[0]} - Url is invalid")
```

How would I integrate the progressbar code? Do I need to put my for loop inside a while loop or vice versa? I assume that "task" needs to be the range of the database table, so it would be while (x < records)? I just can't wrap my head around how I combine these two codes.

Comment: No need for a while loop. Just use your existing for loop. Use the `bar['value']+=10` and `win.update_idletasks()` somewhere near the bottom of the for loop. You may want to change the value 10 so that it depends on how many items there are in records. If there are 25 records then increment the bar by `100/25` each time.

Comment: The whole thing would be better as a seperate process from tkinter but that is a bigger topic to explore.